# Calculating the length at which the probability of maturing reaches 50% in R

Tags: r, regression, probability

I have been having real issues trying to calculate the length at which certain probabilities of maturing are reached. This is NOT the same as the proportion of individuals that are mature as `dose.p` would calculate.

I know I have to run a logistic regression with binomial errors, something similar to the below code

```
mylogit <- glm(Maturity ~ Lngth, data = data, family = "binomial")
```

But from this how can I work out the length at which the probability of maturing equals 50%.
My data frame consists of Maturity (0,1) data and length data. (I have other data but believe this is all I need at this stage (I could be wrong!)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `predict.glm` with `type="response"`and `approx.fun` and then invert that result. Posting data is strongly encouraged on SO if you desire tested solutions. Searching is also recommended.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm new to all this. 
So if Maturity is my response variable, to which i'm looking for length at which 50% probability occurs, and length the predictor. How would my code in R look using the functions you mentioned above. 
I don't know the best way to post code. It's essentially a data frame that looks like this
`'data.frame':   2185 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Lngth   : int  145 155 160 160 165 165 165 170 170 170 ...
 $ Maturity: Factor w/ 2 levels "Immature","Mature": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`
Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: You need to use an accelerated failure time model. This may help http://www.jstatsoft.org/v61/i11/paper

Comment: Searching on the terms `[r] glm dose` pulls up this question and answer that appears to be very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053542/confidence-intervals-for-lethal-dose-ld-for-logistic-regression-in-r. If this is not an exact fit to your problem, then you should post a 1/10th sample of your data using `dput`:   ... `dput( dfrm[ sample(nrow(dfrm), 200) , ])`

Comment: Again, thanks for your quick responses but I am such a novice on here even with the above code I don't understand how I can post you a sample of my data. My lack of coding knowledge is incredibly frustrating! 
So, how does `dput` work? Do I load my data into R first, before somehow cutting some of it out?

Comment: `dput` creates a text version of an object that is unambiguous about the content, unlike the print representation where you cannot tell is a column is a facotr or text, or a Date or text. You just call dput with an expression that can be an object name or as is suggested one that would deliver a smaller verion of your data object. Read `?dput` and run the examples.

Comment: Just type a few lines with some values and spaces in between them.

Comment: @StuartDrew Post the output of a fit model in your question, with the coefficients, `coef(mylogit)`.  I'll work you through an explicit example using your real output.

Comment: Thanks! I think I may have found a way but I would really like to get this to work...
`coef(mylogit)
(Intercept)       
-7.35866780  
Lngth
0.03658587`
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from your comment

> think I may have found a way but I would really like to get this to work... coef(mylogit) (Intercept) -7.35866780 Lngth 0.03658587

it looks like your final model is

$$ \log \left( \frac{Pr(M)}{1 - Pr(M)} \right) = -7.359 + 0.037 L $$

where $M$ is a maturity indicator and $L$ is the measured length.  You would like to know what value of $L$ corresponds to a $Pr(M) = 0.5$.

Substituting your constraint $Pr(M) = 0.5$ into the left hand side, we get

$$ \log \left( \frac{Pr(M)}{1 - Pr(M)} \right) = \log \left( \frac{0.5}{0.5} \right) = \log(1) = 0$$

so the equation we need to solve is

$$ 0 = -7.359 + 0.037 L $$

Now it's easy to solve for $L$

$$ L = \frac{7.539}{0.037} = 203.756 $$

Comment: This is brilliant! You're a star!